# Data by county or by zip code on commercial new construction permits issued across the United States

Tags: data-request, economics, historical, postal-code, county

I am looking for number of new commercial buildings built or permitted at the county or zip code level and would like to know if there is somewhere I can find this for the entire country.  Specifically, I am looking for 5 states - North Carolina, South Carolina, Kentucky, Ohio, and Indiana.  Ideally, the data would include state, zip code, county, date permit issued or building completed, value of property, and intended sector (e.g. restaurant, manufacturing, multifamily) of building.  The data does not need to list every individual building permitted - if I just had number totals by county/zip code, sector, and month/year, that would be sufficient.

Here is a link I found that provides exactly the type of data I'm looking for - however it is only for one county in Maryland:
https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/commercial-permits-6d3e5

If you know of any sources for this type of data, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: The data you are looking for is typically at the county level (like property tax data) or municipal level. You probably are going to have to go county by county lookups